# Updating Values in R dataframe

Tags: r, compare

I'm new to R programming and I would like to know if there's a way to update values by comparing 2 files.

For example, I have my main table, df_table1:

```
Date           Metric1     Metric2     Metric3
1/1/2018       25          4.6         49
2/1/2018       6           3.6         67
3/1/2018       18          2.6         36
4/1/2018       56          3.6         29
```

I am going through various files in a folder iteratively, and I happen to have a file that also contains some overlaps data with the same date values, df_table2:

```
Date           Metric1    Metric2      Metric3
3/1/2018       19         2.9          47
4/1/2018       78         5.7          35
5/1/2018       46         3.3          29
```

Usual way of combining data files would be to use rbind(), but I believe that will create duplicate values for the 2 dates found in df_table2.

Is there a way to do efficiently do a comparison, to check for overlapping dates on all my subsequent files, and replace their corresponding values based on the date in df_table1?

Ideally, it would be even better if there's a way to only do replace, if all metrics in df_table2 have values that are more than the values found in df_table1.

To conlude, I would like the end output to be a combination of df_table1 and df_table2 through some sort of special rbind() function, with values updated from df_table2 without duplicates:

```
Date           Metric1    Metric2      Metric3
1/1/2018       25         4.6          49
2/1/2018       6          3.6          67
3/1/2018       19         2.9          47       #updated from df_table2
4/1/2018       78         5.7          35       #updated from df_table2
5/1/2018       46         3.3          29       #new value from df_table2
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what the final out ought to be. You want df_table2 updated with the respective values of df_table1 (ideally only if the values in df_table1 of a given metrics are below the ones in df_table2). What do you want to do with df_table2 afterwards?

Comment: Hi @SAFEX, thanks for pointing that out. I have mad some changes to show the desired output I would like. I don't exactly need df_table2 after the comparison is done, and to somehow rbind() the updated and new values, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the data first (for the future, please do this yourself to make it easier for people to help you):

```
df_table1= data.frame(Date=c('1/1/2018','2/1/2018','3/1/2018','4/1/2018'), 
Metric1 = c(25,6,18,56),
Metric2 = c(4.6,3.6,2.6,3.6),
Metric3 = c(49,67,36,29))

df_table2= data.frame(Date=c('3/1/2018','4/1/2018','5/1/2018'), Metric1 = c(19,78,46),
Metric2 = c(2.9,5.7,3.3),
Metric3 = c(48,35,29))
```

Next I would merge the tables and then recreate the variables which you need. The first one I wrote for you, the other ones should be easy. Instead of just using the `is.na()` you can compare which variable is larger and pick the one you want.

```
df = merge(df_table1, df_table2, by='Date', all=TRUE)
df$Metric1 = df$Metric1.y
df$Metric1[is.na(df$Metric1)]  = df$Metric1.x[is.na(df$Metric1)] 
df
   Date    Metric1.x Metric2.x Metric3.x Metric1.y Metric2.y Metric3.y Metric1
1 1/1/2018        25       4.6        49        NA        NA        NA      25
2 2/1/2018         6       3.6        67        NA        NA        NA       6
3 3/1/2018        18       2.6        36        19       2.9        48      19
4 4/1/2018        56       3.6        29        78       5.7        35      78
5 5/1/2018        NA        NA        NA        46       3.3        29      46
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. the metrics should be all in a dataframe, and not be all seperate vectors. I'm looking for a solution that helps me to do rbind() while allowing an update of values. Hoped my clarifications help to make more sense of the question

Comment: not sure I understand. my solution stores the "final values" in one dataframe (called `df`). If `df_table2` gets a new observation (e.g. `6/1/2018`), just rerun the code, and it will get all datapoints.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
rbind(df_table1,df_table2) %>% group_by(Date) %>% filter(Metric1==max(Metric1))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Date [5]
  Date     Metric1 Metric2 Metric3
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1/1/2018     25.    4.60     49.
2 2/1/2018      6.    3.60     67.
3 3/1/2018     19.    2.90     48.
4 4/1/2018     78.    5.70     35.
5 5/1/2018     46.    3.30     29.
```

Note that this assumes that if Metric1 is larger in one table than it is in another, then so will all the other metrics be. It wasn't clear to me what happens if this is not the case.

Here's the oddly elaborate code that will keep one row for each date in both tables, keeping either the row where all the metrics are larger than in the other row, OR, if neither row matches that rule, it will keep the row from table1:

First, let's change the data a little bit:

```
df_table1= data.frame(Date=c('1/1/2018','2/1/2018','3/1/2018','4/1/2018'), 
                      Metric1 = c(25,6,18,56),
                      Metric2 = c(4.6,3.6,2.6,6.3),
                      Metric3 = c(49,67,36,29), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_table2= data.frame(Date=c('3/1/2018','4/1/2018','5/1/2018'), Metric1 = c(19,78,46),
                      Metric2 = c(2.9,5.7,3.3),
                      Metric3 = c(48,35,29), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now the Jan 4th row will have Metric 2 higher on one row while the other metrics higher on the other one.

```
rbind(df_table1,df_table2) %>% 
group_by(Date) %>% 
mutate(keeper=(Metric1==max(Metric1) & Metric2==max(Metric2) & Metric3==max(Metric3))) %>% 
group_by(Date,keeper) %>% 
filter(row_number()==1) %>% 
group_by(Date) %>% add_count() %>% 
mutate(keeper=ifelse(n==1,TRUE,keeper)) %>% 
filter(keeper) %>% select(-keeper, -n)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Date [5]
  Date     Metric1 Metric2 Metric3
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1/1/2018     25.    4.60     49.
2 2/1/2018      6.    3.60     67.
3 4/1/2018     56.    6.30     29.
4 3/1/2018     19.    2.90     48.
5 5/1/2018     46.    3.30     29.
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to achieve this, but I don't know what it is - I got to this with a lot of trial and error...

Lastly, if you decide you want to just keep the table1 version if there are duplicate dates, regardless of the metrics, do this:

```
rbind(df_table1,df_table2) %>%  filter(!duplicated(Date))
      Date Metric1 Metric2 Metric3
1 1/1/2018      25     4.6      49
2 2/1/2018       6     3.6      67
3 3/1/2018      18     2.6      36
4 4/1/2018      56     6.3      29
5 5/1/2018      46     3.3      29
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will try to read up on dplyr.

So if I don't need to care about whether Metric1 is larger or not, i just have to remove that filter?

Comment: If you remove the filter you'll still have the duplicates - you need to filter them out somehow...

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df_table1%>%
  anti_join(df_table2, by = c('Date'))%>%
  rbind(data= . ,df_table2)
```

Comment: why it is rated downwards ? this produces exactly according to the requirements of the Answer. Anti join will leave you with what you have in df1 and not in df2. since you have left out what was common in between two tables , you can now get  all the data from df2 and bind it with df1. This eliminates the duplicates and also makes sure that you get the updated information from df2